# Should I use "brothers" to refer to a mixed gender collection of siblings?

Tags: grammatical-number, kinship-terms

I know I can use siblings, but this seems strange in some contexts.
Let's say I am opening a lemonade booth with my sister and I want to call the company "Lemon Bros."; would that be correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what contexts you find it strange to use *siblings* to refer to your siblings, but I would find it strange to encounter a lemonade stand named "Lemon Bros" populated with women (or girls).

Comment: Absolutely not. Would you mind if she decided to call it the "Lemon Sisters"?

Comment: Possibly a "lemon party."

Comment: "Almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts [and] references" doesn't make sense to me here.  Isn't it more the opposite -- entirely answerable based on references found in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

Consulting a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brother) for "brother," we find that all definitions (except possibly the slangy use meaning "buddy") require that the individual referred to be male.  So no, it's not correct.

You may be thinking by analogy to "man," as in, "No man is an island," in which there is no requirement that the individual be male.  But one of the definitions of "man" (the second one, in [this dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/man?s=t)) is one without that requirement:  "a member of the species *Homo sapiens* or all the members of this species collectively, without regard to sex."

Names for businesses, bands, troupes, imprints, etc., need not be literally descriptive.  The Thompson Twins were three people that weren't related.  The Doobie Brothers weren't brothers.  Organically Grown clothing wasn't grown organically, and Mars Bars have nothing to do with the planet or the god.   So you can take that name, but it won't literally describe your brother-sister pair.

Answer (score 0):

Biologists often shorten "siblings" to "sibs".  "Lemon sibs" has a nice ring to it, doesn't it?